# Adding a variable in this statement (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c

How do add a variable in this statement:

```
Params:@{@"where" : @"postTitle='aaa'"}
```

I want to add a predefined NSString in place of the 'aaa'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Just curious, why would you need to add a variable like that as parems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is creating a dictionary with a key of "where" and a value of "postTitle='aaa'".

What you need to do is to add another statement that builds your value into another variable. Something like this:

```
NSString *valueString= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"postTitle='%@'",
  titleValue];
[yourMethodCall... Params:@{@"where" : valueString} ]
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.